# Javascript: unique location.href

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

**Hi,**

I am currently working on this autocomplete-searchbox, and as untutored I am when it comes to JavaScript i wonder: how do i give each value an specific unique link to another .html page? So that *'Desserts'* links to *page1.html* & *'Snacks'* to *page2.html*?

As you can see are all the values currently linking to *location.href = "http://www.cnn.com";* but i want to give each value a specific location.href..

Best regards

```
$(function(){

   var term = [  

    { value: 'Desserts' },

    { value: 'Snacks'},

    { value: 'Drinks'},

    { value: 'Cheesecake'},

    { value: 'Cookies'},

  ];

  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: term,

  onSelect: function myFunction() {
    location.href = "http://www.cnn.com";
}
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the direction you want to head. If you post more of what you have I can give you a more specific answer

```
 $(function(){
   var term = [{ 
     value: 'Desserts', 
     location: 'page1.html' 
  },{ 
     value: 'Snacks', 
     location: 'page2.html' 
  }, { 
     value: 'Drinks', 
     location: 'page3.html' 
  }, { 
     value: 'Cheesecake', 
     location: 'page4.html'
  }, { 
     value: 'Cookies', 
     location: 'page5.html'
  },];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
  lookup: term,
  onSelect: function myFunction(e) {
    //Depending on how you trigger onSelect e.currentTarget.location 
    //may or may not work. but you should be able to start with e 
    //and work your way to finding location.
    location.href = "http://www.cnn.com"+e.currentTarget.location;
  }
});
});
```

Also you could look into a library with a built in autocomplete and the documentation that goes with it. JQuery have something you could look into here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works fine in such way that the value comes up in the box, but i still don't get redirected to an extern .html document